# FileZilla: "Too many authentication failures for ubuntu" when i do sftp to my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp

I have been using my AWS EC2 instance from last 6 months, but now when I use sftp, I keep getting this error.

```
Error:          Server sent disconnect message
Error:          type 2 (protocol error):
Error:          "Too many authentication failures for ubuntu"
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: What is Ubuntu version you are using

Comment: try to allow sftp firewall to your instance by 'ufw allow 22'

Comment: Post your complete `scp` command.

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar i'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: did u enable firewall to your instance

Comment: @helloV i'm doing sftp using FileZilla

Comment: Once u follow this instructions https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar, yeah i did. I can do SSH through command-line though, but i can't able do stfp through FileZilla from last week.

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar, sure...

Comment: It is likely you have more keys in `~/.ssh` now. Delete the unneeded keys or move the unneeded keys from `~/.ssh` and keep no more than 4 keys in `~/.ssh`. If it works, I'll tell you the reason why.

Comment: @helloV, thank you so much. I can able to connect now. There were more than 20 keys in my .ssh. I deleted unused and I can able to connect to it now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Filezilla` tries all the keys in `~/.ssh` directory and the `ssh` daemon on most OS will deny access after 5 attempts with the message `Too many authentication failures`

Delete the unneeded keys or move the unneeded keys from `~/.ssh` and keep no more than 4 keys in `~/.ssh`

Comment: My issue was the SSH agent did not have my key added. Running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/specific_id_rsa` solved it for me.

Comment: @DaveLak You comment fixed it for me.